# Duplicate a record in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm currently displaying an array of members using PHP and I'm trying to duplicate every record. The code looks as following:

```
<?php
      $count = count($member);
      for ( $row = 0; $row<$count; $row++ )
    { 
    ?>
    <li>
       <?php echo $member[$row]['Firstname']; ?> <?php echo $member[$row]['Lastname']; ?>
    </li>
<?php } ?>
```

How could I make it print the record 2 times? Thank you!

Comment: You duplicate the code ... ? Just copy paste everything from `<li>` to `</li>`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
  $count = count($member);
  for ( $row = 0; $row<$count; $row++ )
{
$data = $member[$row]; 
?>
<li>
   <?php echo $data['Firstname']; ?> <?php echo $data['Lastname']; ?>
</li>
<li>
   <?php echo $data['Firstname']; ?> <?php echo $data['Lastname']; ?>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

This has worked:

```
<?php
      $count = count($member);
      for($row = 0; $row < $count; $row++) {
      for($j = 1; $j <= 2; $j++) { 
    ?>
    <li>
       <?php echo $member[$row]['Firstname']; ?> <?php echo $member[$row]['Lastname']; ?>
    </li>
```